# Angular 2 CORS issue only when using 'toPromise' but not Observables

Tags: angular

Here is the error that I get when using 'toPromise' on a POST call:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.
>   Redirect from 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' to
>   'https://captcha.gecirtnotification.com/pitc/?url=http%3a%2f%2fjsonplacehold…212596678@ge.com&lang=en_US&zsq=QZsC6JP75b8Z54VNTsJSKHnnWH0WsC6JPMpb6Vszsq'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is
>   disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

I am making a basic POST call to jsonplaceholders mock API (http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

I only get the above error when using the 'toPromise' implementation. It works when using Observables. I am not sure how/why the promise/observable resolution is affecting the actual POST call and/or preflight calls.

This (using toPromise) fails:

```
public testPostCall(): any {
    let url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let payload = {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": undefined,
        "title": "Test API Title",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    };

    return this.http.post(url, payload, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response: Response) => {
            console.log('post response', response);
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

This (using Observables) works:

```
public testPostCall(): any {
    let url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let payload = {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": undefined,
        "title": "Test API Title",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    };

    return this.http.post(url, payload, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log('post response', response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here are the imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Comment: Hmmh, tested your code and it works fine... Have you tried to reproduce the issue in a plunker? And there should be no issue with cors either since they are allowing it on jsonplaceholder.

Comment: I was having issues with HTTPS in plunker. I can send a git repo later, I am currently having an issue posting one while at work. 

Interestingly enough, when I started a fresh project from the angular-cli, I got that error with both Promise and Observable.

Comment: Hmm from what you've posted I didn't see you `subscribe` to the observable, which means the request has never been sent to server. Did you get the results from that test call using observables?

Comment: @HarryNinh, OP has stated that it works with observables in the question, the issue is with promises ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 That's what I'm trying to debunk. It should not work in either case if the CORS issue presents. I want to know if it's simply that he didn't get any error, or he did actually get back the correct data from the POST request.

Comment: This is looking more and more like a corporate proxy issue. I've hit the error using both methods now. Still not sure why it was behaving the way it was, but I think there are higher level issues.

Comment: @AJT_82 , if it still matters, I was getting correct data back with POST request.

Comment: Any solution...?